# How do we tell from the log of a chkdsk, check success or fail?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, chkdsk

I did a `chkdsk C: /r` and this is what I had from event viewer:

```
Checking file system on C:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is ACER.

A disk check has been scheduled.
Windows will now check the disk.                         
  475584 file records processed.                                     1200 large file records processed.                               0 bad file records processed.                                 0 EA records processed.                                       78 reparse records processed.                                  621356 index entries processed.                                    0 unindexed files processed.                                  475584 security descriptors processed.                           Cleaning up 75 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 75 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 75 unused security descriptors.
  72887 data files processed.                                     CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  34798616 USN bytes processed.                                      Usn Journal verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)...
  475568 files processed.                                          File data verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying free space (stage 5 of 5)...
  28329215 free clusters processed.                                  Free space verification is complete.
Adding 1 bad clusters to the Bad Clusters File.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.
Windows has made corrections to the file system.

 488384511 KB total disk space.
 374279384 KB in 400388 files.
    187836 KB in 72888 indexes.
         4 KB in bad sectors.
    600431 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 113316856 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 122096127 total allocation units on disk.
  28329214 allocation units available on disk.

Internal Info:
c0 41 07 00 c6 38 07 00 ba 66 0c 00 00 00 00 00  .A...8...f......
57 01 00 00 4e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  W...N...........
42 00 00 00 52 73 2c 77 08 9a 05 00 08 92 05 00  B...Rs,w........

Windows has finished checking your disk.
Please wait while your computer restarts.
```

I was wondering how do we see through the log to determine if the hard disk is having errors. Does the `4 KB in bad sectors` mean that there's something wrong with the harddisk?

==
Windows Vista Home Premium sp 2

Comment: I start my Saturdays by running CHKDSK C: /F . Therapeutic for me, hopefully for the HDD too.

Comment: C: /r is c: /f implied right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that chkdsk has discovered a bad sector on the hard disk which means that the drive itself may not necessarily be bad yet but is not a good sign.  This sector has been mapped in a table that keeps track of bad sectors so that Windows knows not to use it. Essentially Windows has corrected the problem by remapping the data from that bad sector to a known good one.

The next step would be to test the health of the drive.  You can test the health of the hard drive with a variety of different tools, I like [DFT](http://www.hitachigst.com/support/downloads/#DFT) but there are certainly others.  If the results from the drive test show a disk to be failing you definitely have failing disk and should replace it immediately.

You may also be able to get away with remapping the bad sector(s) in the short term using special tools like [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/) or [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) or you could check to see if the drive is under warranty, in which case you may be able to RMA it.

If the drive has even just one bad sector it would be a good idea start looking into a replacement for it, IMO.  And, as always, back up your important data.

Comment: Does the 4KB in bad sectors listed above means 4KB in bad sectors fixed or 4KB in bad sectors remaining?

Comment: Windows has made corrections to the file system.  There are 4KB of bad sectors, but they've been marked "DO NOT USE", basically.

Comment: @Rob ic. so I'm having 4kb less storage (which isn't a big deal) ?

Comment: Slightly more because it keeps track and that takes storage, but it's negligible for such a small amount. Getting bad sectors is, well, *bad*, so you might want to look into getting a new hard drive if you're attached to your data.